# Perspective stuck to one object

Tags: vertices

I have quite a simple but for me, even after several attempts and research, unfixable problem.
I'm quite unexperienced with Blender so please don't judge me :).

The problem: I was modelling a 3D-object, and (probably after a missused shortcut?) my perspective bound to a sphere I used for a shape in an object. Now I have no option to select vertices from other parts of the object. The top left corner shows: "User Perspective (0) Scene Collection | Sphere". How do I change my Perspective so I can normally edit every part of the object?

Sorry that the question is so simple but for me thats a problem and I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably pressed <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> and toggled *Local View*. Press it again to disable it. Alternatively, use the *View -> Local View -> Toggle Local View* in GUI.

[image: screenshot of the GUI menu]

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot!